# SourceTree submodule update - why is it executed?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Every time I switch to different branch via SourceTree it executes this command (besides switching branch command)

```bash
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree submodule update --init --recursive
```

What's the point of it?

Answer (score 2):

A submodule is referenced in the parent repo as a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309), which points to the SHA1 of the sub-repo.

Whenever you are switching branch, that entry can change, meaning the sub-repo should be checked out again, at a different SHA1.

That is exactly what a [`git submodule update --init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-update--init--remote-N--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f--force--checkout--rebase--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--ltpathgt82308203) does.

> the `init` and `update` subcommands will maintain submodules checked out and at appropriate revision in your working tree.